# Align 2 divs in same line without using float

Tags: html, css, web

I am a new learner in web designing and practicing websites. I want to align 2 divs in one line without using float. I have a parent div with width 1400px. I want 2 child divs of width 600px each to align next to each other and have equal margin from both sides. Below is my code. Please suggest.

Also, what changes does float make to DOM? I observed that if I use float I need to specify the height as well? Is it the case or I was making some mistake in understanding the role of float?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      My Page
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

.main{
  width:1400px;
  background-color:#c3c3c3;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child1{
  background-color:#666;
  width: 600px;
  margin:auto;
}
.child2{
  background-color:#888;
  width : 600px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this.

```css
.main {
  width: 1400px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.child1 {
  background-color: #666;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child2 {
  background-color: #888;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Or you can Improve you `css` to this.

```css
.main {
  width: 1400px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.main div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
.main div.child1 {
  background-color: #666;
}
.main div.child2 {
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox like this:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with:

```
.main div { display: inline-block; }
```

Expect a whitespace between the divs.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (at least roughly):

```
.main{
  width:1400px;
  background-color:#c3c3c3;
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
}
.child1{
  background-color:#666;
  width: 600px;
  margin:auto;
  display: table-cell;
}
.child2{
  background-color:#888;
  width : 600px;
  margin:auto;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Float is really intended to put a picture (or a similar element) on one side of the page and have the text flow around it. It's often "abused" to pack elements next to each other horizontally, but that creates its own problems.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers you've been given are good, and people have been doing this since CSS became a thing. Another way you *can* do it, and really whichever method you'd like depends solely on your circumstances is by using `position:relative` on the parent wrapper, and `position:absolute` any the child elements.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 50vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper > div {
  position: absolute;
}
.wrapper .first {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 48vw;
  border:1px dotted green;
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper .second {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 48vw;
  border:1px dashed orange;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    This is content number 1
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    This is content number two.
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way is by setting the container div to display as a row, and then have the two child elements be displayed as table cells. Tables were kind of the old-go-to back before CSS became extensive (*can you believe there was a time before `border-radius`?*)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 48%;
}
.first {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.second {
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    First Child
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    Second Child
  </div>

</div>
```

Really there's a bunch, you just need to figure out which one works best for you.